# Storyboards vs. doing it in code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, cocoa-touch

I'm working in a company where we have several iOS developers and we use GIT to work in the same projects together. We never use Storyboards or .xib files in our development process as it's nearly impossible to merge them correctly.

With the introduction of the iOS7 I thought about the fundamental differences between Storyboards and coding all the UI "the old way", without the use of Interface Builder.

Is there anyone here who does just that? And most importantly, is there something you CAN do in Storyboards that you can't do in code in XCode 5?

Comment: There is nothing you can do in storyboard and can't do in code. Objects, gesture recognizers, segues, even constraints - are all available for you to build programmatically.

Comment: @nemesis concerning the segue for example, aren't they used in storyboards only? I principally use `[self.navigationController pushViewController...]` or just `presentViewController`

Comment: Segues are created much easier in storyboards (just like everything else) but you could also create them programmatically. Personally, I've never done that, but the [UIStoryboardSegue documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says that you can use `initWithIdentifier:source:destination:` to create a segue.

Comment: actually, using storyboards are just generating the same code on the background. So with that logic every action and property in storyboard must have a code equal..

Comment: @nemesis: there are things you cannot do without Storyboards. Segues, for example, are not intended to be created by code (from the docs: “You do not create segue objects directly. Instead, the storyboard runtime creates them when it must perform a segue between two view controllers.”). The initializer is documented in case you need to subclass. Another thing you can only do with storyboards and not with code or xibs, as far as I know, is static table view cells.

Comment: Never avoid storyboards.

Always use storyboard approach in 100% of situations.

Anything else is ridiculous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to split your question into two: NIBs, and storyboards.

As far as NIBs are concerned, source control issues can be painful but manageable, mainly because you've typically got one NIB file per view controller. You could imagine a situation where you have two developers working on two different sections of your NIB powered app without any merging issues. Storyboards are different, since you have one single file that describes most - if not all - of the UI of your application. Clearly there is a far greater potential for conflict issues there.

NIBs can be extremely useful and time saving, if used correctly. Here's an example: the iPhoto App on iPad has a very complex UI. The vast majority of that UI is laid out programatically. *However*, the app also uses NIBs to load in graphical elements which are then laid out in code. This is how the brush panel works - all the brushes are created in a NIB. This means that Apple *don't* have to have dozens of identical image/image view alloc/init pieces of code. All the creation can happen in a NIB (this was discussed in some detail in a WWDC 2012 session on the iPhoto UI - it's well worth tracking down).

So NIBs - sometimes good, can save you a lot of time, and whilst there *are* merge issues they can in many cases be easily managed and handled.

Then we come to storyboards. Storyboards are interesting. On the one hand, they are extremely helpful and useful for straightforward apps and developers new to the platform. I've just converted a `UINavigationController` based app from NIBs to storyboards and found some significant time savings (particularly around table views, since with storyboards you can take advantage of prototype cells).

However, if you're working on a large scale project with several developers I'm not convinced storyboards are that beneficial. There are, as you say, big issues with merge conflicts, and unlike NIBs it's not easy to resolve them since that single storyboard file controls *all* of your app UI.

Here's what I'd suggest (and feel free to ignore me!) - if you're currently developing apps and doing your layout/UI *entirely* in code consider whether NIBs might save you time. They may well not - they're not for everybody - but it's well worth at least considering. You may be surprised at how many large apps actually use NIBs (iPhoto, as I mentioned, but also many built-in apps provided by Apple, as well as many popular third party apps by large teams). I probably *wouldn't* consider storyboards unless you were a sole developer working on an app with fairly straightforward navigation. That's not to do down storyboards in any way - I love using them - it's just they're not really suitable for collaboration.

Somebody posted this comment in reply to your question - I wanted to discuss it:

> There is nothing you can do in storyboard and can't do in code. Objects, gesture recognizers, segues, even constraints - are all available for you to build programmatically

This is *technically* true, but in reality there are things in storyboards/NIBs that are **much easier** than code. A good example of this is auto layout. Whilst you can certainly manage your auto layout contraints entirely in code, the harsh reality is that the ASCII auto layout representation is much harder to work with than the visual representation you get in IB. This is *especially* true on XCode 5, where there are massive improvements to auto layout in IB (I can't detail it too much as it's still under NDA, but Apple publically talk a bit about the [changes here](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html)).

Comment: Don't forget that you can have multiple storyboards just as you can have multiple nibs.

Comment: "There is nothing you can do in storyboard and can't do in code," is like saying "There is nothing you can do in Objective-C and can't do in assembler." It's true, but there are productivity differences.

Comment: It is true that vanilla NSConstraints are a special kind of pain which should be avoided. But there is DSLs that help a *lot*, check out Snapkit.

Comment: The productivity differences are so mindbogglingly enormous that you can't even look at it as the same category of thing.  Consider for example that you ***do not actually literally need Photoshop to retouch 80mb raw PNG images if you're a wedding photographer.***  Of course not! You can just open it in text edit and change the bytes!

Answer (score 3):

For me the only big drawback of storyboards is the slow loading time and the usual lag that comes when navigating the storyboard. I'm not talking about 2-5 view controllers apps. I'm talking about 10 and more...

My personal preference is smaller storyboards if I really have to use them(UITableView prototype cells) or just plain xibs.

Doing it in just plain code is just a matter of .... do you have enough time on your hands? :) Usually you wont gain a lot from doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider these issues in your dessision:

**Development time -**

Obviously, working with the xcode UI designer is much more faster and easy to learn when creating new applications from scratch.
In the programmatically way, you will have to define in code each and every element property you'll want to set.
Working with storyboard will make the development process much faster.

**Code reuse -**

When working with storyboard you will have to bind UI elements to the controller with bullets that adds additional hidden code in the storyboard file. Same stubs are added when creating segues between controller.
This addition hidden code will make make it more difficult to reuse the controllers in other apps that you'll build.
If you are planning to make mass reuse of you controllers code, than creating the UI elements programmatically will be more suitable.

**Source code integration -**

Conflicts resolving is a common thing when several developers commits changes to the file. 
Creating and changing UI elements with storyboard additional changes are added to the storyboard file that sometimes makes the conflicts resolve kind of tricky.
On the other hand, when changing UI elements programmatically only the changes that you'll make will be added the the controller file.